# A little complex path matching in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm new to Akka HTTP, and trying to write my first API. The routing DSL seems a little confusing.

I managed to match the following:

/channel
/channel/*channelName*

But now I need to match the following:

/channel/*channelName*/*channelAction*

And I can't get it to work.

I currently have:

```
private val routes: Route =
    path("channel") {
      get {
        reportAllChannelsStatus()
      }
    } ~
    pathPrefix("channel" / Remaining) { channelName =>
      get {
        singleChannelRequest(channelName, status)
      } ~
      post {
        entity(as[ChannelRequest]) { request =>
          singleChannelRequest(channelName, request.channelAction)
        }
      }
    } ~
    completeWith404()
```

I want to add get and post for /channel/*channelName*/*channelAction*

Any idea how is this done? (extract both *channelName* and *channelAction*)

Comment: FWIW, if you have the choice, you might want to consider Play for your web apps. I know it doesn't answer your question, but it's much better suited.

Comment: @erip I am implementing an HTTP API on an already huge system that uses Akka Actors, and Akka HTTP Client to make external requests, so I decided to go with Akka HTTP, which everything needed in already included in the project.

Comment: Every other thing in the Lightbend stack ues Akka actors extensively, Play included.

Comment: Akka http is totally fine for API writing, and I believe you'll find no more value for writing API in Play. For full web backend (like e.g if you need to render web pages), maybe you'll want to go Play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match

```
path("channel" / Segment / Segment){
   (channelName, channelAction) => ...
}
```

Be aware that for different types of arguments, you'll have to match different things. `Segment` is for `String`, `IntNumber` would be for `Int` ...

Comment: If I may suggest it, I'd replace in your codebase Remaining with Segment for cases where you know you just want to match a String. Remaining will happily give you slashes and stuff, and make it difficult to control sub levels matching. 

In any case, you're welcome :-)

Comment: I did! Thanks. This is what I ended with: https://pastebin.com/e3T9pSKk